# apache2 not load php in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

the question: apache not load the php，cannot parse php file

the basic situation:

1. have nginx in ubuntu
2. have not php7.0.conf and php7.0.load in etc/apache2/mods-available
3. `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )`

I try something:

- i try to use php-frm
- load something model

  sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf 
  sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.load 
  sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_fcgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_fcgi.load

2.load php-fpm in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
</IfModule>
```

but the above is invalid

I find the file of `php7.0-fpm.conf` in `/etc/apache2/conf-available`
so, I want to apache2 load php, parse php file

Comment: `have nginx in ubuntu` Please decide: Apache or nginx. Acording to your question, you have nginx, but are trying to configure apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried to solve the err
include:
`apt-get --purge remove apache2` and delete apache configure files `find /etc -name "*apache2*" |xargs rm -rf` `rm -rf /etc/inir.d/apache2` etc

suddenly i remember,may，the php miss mode
so i try to 'apt-get install libapache2-mod-php' to answer the question

i'm sad，simple problem to complications